# Regular expressions in Go that span multiple lines

Tags: regex, go

Is it possible in Go to break a complex regular expression using multiple lines? It would help a lot to create a more readable code.

For example in Scala, Ruby, JavaScript it is possible to use `x` flag:

`x — Free-spacing and line comments (aka extended mode)`

And it allows to write regular expression like:

```
  TAXON_CONCEPTS2 = /\s+
                     (\(?s\.\s?s\.|
                     \(?s\.\s?l\.|
                     \(?s\.\s?str\.|
                     \(?s\.\s?lat\.|
                    sec\.|sec|near)\b.*$/x
```

I would like to achieve similar code in Go instead of:

```
var taxonConceptsRe2 = regexp.MustCompile(`(,\s*|\s+)(\(?s\.\s?s\.|\(?s\.\s?l\.|\(?s\.\s?str\.|\(?s\.\s?lat\.).*$`)
```

Comment: No. The regexp syntax is well-documented: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/

Comment: I wonder what was a rationale, Go seem to value readability as an important design goal.

Comment: Motivation for design decisions is a question for the designers, not the community.

Comment: hopefully designers are part of the community?

Comment: They may be, but SO is for asking a question of the community at large. If there is a specific person who can answer your question and likely no one else, your question should be directed at them, not the community.

Comment: As there are no regexp _literals_ in Go you do not need this feature: You parse a string and you can break up your string and reassemble that string with `+` which lets you split your "regexp" over several lines just as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you @Volker, now I understood the rationale of not including 'x' flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options to improve readability of a regular expression like this.

1. Split the string:

   ```
   pattern := `(,\s*|\s+)` +
       `(\(?s\.\s?s\.|` +
       `\(?s\.\s?l\.|` +
       `\(?s\.\s?str\.|` +
       `\(?s\.\s?lat\.).*$`
   ```
2. Pre-parse the string:

   ```
   pattern := strings.Replace(`\s+
                    (\(?s\.\s?s\.|
                    \(?s\.\s?l\.|
                    \(?s\.\s?str\.|
                    \(?s\.\s?lat\.|
                   sec\.|sec|near)\b.*$`,
           "\n                ", "", -1)
   ```

   If you choose this approach, you'll probably want to build a function to do this for you, and to be a bit more robust.
3. Don't use a regexp. (Obviously not always ideal, but regexes are often very overused, so do this one if it makes sense.)

Answer (score 3):

Laying out using + looks slightly better and at least splits up the regexp

```
var taxonConceptsRe2 = regexp.MustCompile(
    `(,\s*|\s+)(\(?s\.\s?s\.|` +
        `\(?s\.\s?l\.|` +
        `\(?s\.\s?str\.|` +
        `\(?s\.\s?lat\.).*$`)
```